overload typing for variable amount of arguments (`args` or `kwargs`)
Example is below, need to make sure IDE type checker or reveal_type would identify k, j and i types correctly.
Perhaps there is some way to suggest the typing that args is an empty tuple and kwargs empty dict and the return value then would be tuple[int]?
from typing import Union, overload

def test(*args: int, **kwargs: str) -> Union[int, str, tuple[int]]:
    if args:
        return 5
    if kwargs:
        return "5"
    return (5,)


# now all are Union[int, str, tuple[int]]
k = test(1)
j = test(i="1")
i = test()

reveal_type(k) # should be int
reveal_type(j) # should be str
reveal_type(i) # should be tuple[int]


Here's a possible solution that allows mypy to infer the correct types for k, j, and i. This approach does result in mypy complaining about the overload signatures overlapping. I'm not sure if it's possible to address that besides simply suppressing the errors.
from typing import Union, overload


@overload
def test() -> tuple[int]:  # type: ignore[overload-overlap]
    ...
    
@overload
def test(*args: int) -> int:  # type: ignore[overload-overlap]
    ...
    
@overload
def test(**kwargs: str) -> str:
    ...

def test(*args: int, **kwargs: str) -> Union[int, str, tuple[int]]:
    if args:
        return 5
    if kwargs:
        return "5"
    return (5,)


# now all are Union[int, str, tuple[int]]
k = test(1)
j = test(i="1")
i = test()

reveal_type(k) # should be int
reveal_type(j) # should be str
reveal_type(i) # should be tuple[int]

Output from mypy --strict v1.9.0 (try it online!):
main.py:29: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
main.py:30: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
main.py:31: note: Revealed type is "tuple[builtins.int]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file


the second variant does overlap with the first, so ignoring it's a bug. You can fix that by making the second def test(arg: int, *args: int, /) -> int: (not sure if the / is in the right place)
